# How get the current latitude, longitude, and zoom in jquery gmap3

Tags: jquery, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get current latitude and longitude from gps enabled device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452217/get-current-latitude-and-longitude-from-gps-enabled-device)

I use the gmap3 of http://gmap3.net.
I want to get the latitude, longitude, and zoom on the change event.
This api has a get:

http://gmap3.net/api/get.html

But i try `$('.gmap_widget').gmap3('get','map');`

and returns a doom node '.gmap_widget'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `$('.gmap_widget').gmap3('get','map');` is wrong

The correct form is `$('.gmap_widget').gmap3({action:'get',name:'map'});`

The code is:

```
   map=$('.gmap_widget').gmap3({action:'get',name:'map'});
   center=map.getCenter();
   lat=center.lat();
   lng=center.lng();
   zoom=map.getZoom();
```

New API will use the following:

```
var map = $(".gmap_widget").gmap3({ 
  get: {
    name:'map',
    callback: function(map){ 
       center=map.getCenter();
       lat=center.lat();
       lng=center.lng();
       zoom=map.getZoom();  
  }} 
});
```