# Javascript code not fetching location longitude and latitude for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, mobile, location

My javascript code not fetching longitude and latitude from mobile chrome browser.

the below-given code is working for laptop or desktop browser but not mobile

```
<script>
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
   function showPosition(position) {
        alert(position.coords.latitude);
         alert(position.coords.longitude);
        document.getElementById("input1").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("input2").value = position.coords.longitude;
}
    </script>
```

display or get longitude and latitude on the website browser.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452217/get-current-latitude-and-longitude-from-gps-enabled-device) may help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I am already using chrome v 74.0.3 mobile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [geolocation not work in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330219/geolocation-not-work-in-mobile)

Comment: maybe you should post your html, too

Comment: @AravindhNagarajan thank you but even this not working for desktop browser.

Comment: @OrangeOrange it is javascript  and it automatic fetch L&L but not working for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different browser in mobile it should work.

You can also add **handle_error** callback function to understand the issue more clearly.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,handle_error);

function handle_error(err){
 if(err.code == 1)
 {
   //User denied permission
 }
 else if(err.code == 2)
 {
   //position unavailable
 }
 else if(err.code == 3)
 {
   //Timeout
 }
 else{
   //Some other error
 }
}
```