# How to print HTML geolocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using HTML5 Geolocation and wants to print the returned user location in the input field.

Is this possible? If so how?

```js
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You don't have any HTML element with id `demo` ??

Comment: Sorry I just edited the code.

Comment: Your code works for me. On chrome, it pops up and asks for permission before displaying my geocoordinates. Have you granted permission? (Permission in chrome chrome://settings/content/location?search=permission)

Comment: When I click on Allow, it doesn't show me latitude or longitude. It works until the popup for permission.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have edited the answer. the problem in your code was that the variable x was coming null since you were trying to do getElemntById for the p tag not defined in the code yet.so I have put the HTML part above the javascript code.


 <input type="text">
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    console.log(x);
       function getLocation() {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
         } else {
           x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
         }
       }

       function showPosition(position) {
         x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
         "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
       }
       </script>
```

Comment: This is my code as it is. And it's not working with this.

Comment: I have edited the answer. the problem in your code was that the variable x was coming null since you were trying to do getElemntById for the p tag not defined in the code yet.so I have put the HTML part above the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the error to know the root cause, it could be possible that the position is unavailable

[Check the way to handle error in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324225/9223414)

instead of assigning the values directly to **x.innerHTML** first, check if you are getting the position coordinates using **console.log**

```
function showPosition(position) {
         console.log(position)
        // x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        // "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
       }
```

and then once you successfully receive the position details, assign it to your variable

```
function showPosition(position) {
            // console.log(position)
             x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
             "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
           }
```